Reference for a proof of the identity $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)\ln^2k}k=-2 \gamma$?
Can you please provide me a reference for a proof of the identity
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu\left(k\right)\ln^{2}\left(k\right)}k
= -2\gamma\ ?.
$$
This is an identity involving the Mobius function.

Please format your formulas, and include your question in tbe body of your post. Is it really a reference that you want, or a proof? What for, and what were your attempts to prove that formula?

This identity contains two assertions - the fact that the series converges and the fact that the sum is $-2\gamma$.
The second assertion follows from the first and (the Dirichlet series version of) Abel's Theorem which says that if $\sum a_n/n$ converges then $f(s)=\sum a_nn^{-s}$ is analytic for $\Re s >1$ and $\sum a_n/n=\lim_{s \to 1^+}f(s)$ (with the limit existing automatically) applied to $f(s)=(\frac{1}{\zeta(s)})''$ and $a_n=\mu(n)\log^2 n$.
Since $\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma+(s-1)h(s)$ it immediately follows (by identifying coefficients in the relation $\zeta(s) \times \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=1$) that $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=s-1-\gamma (s-1)^2+h_1(s)(s-1)^3$ so $(\frac{1}{\zeta(s)})''(1)=-2\gamma$
The convergence part is nontrivial and follows from the PNT version in terms of Mobius functions with small enough error:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\mu(n)<<_A N\log^{-A}N$$ by choosing any $A>2$ and summing by parts.
